# using valition in toolbox in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, web, toolbox

I'd like to use valition in toolbox to validate my forms,but it seems something wrong. If I open toolbox,there are only HTML en General tags available.

If you right-mouse klink 'show all',i can well find 'Validation' tag,but the items are not available to me. I also try to reset,but it still doesn't working. I can't figure out why.

I use ASP.NET Core Web Application in visual studio 2017 version 15.4.3
 see the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: i think you need to switch from markup to design view to enable those toolbox items.